# как изменить возвращаемый тип void на Future<DateTime> через onChange:

Tags: flutter

```
static const int firstYearDiff = 40;

Future<DateTime?> buildCupertinoDatePicker({
  required BuildContext context,
  required ValueNotifier<DateTime> controller,
  String format = 'yyyy',
}) {
  return ValueListenableBuilder<DateTime>(
    valueListenable: controller,
    builder: (context, value, child) {
      return DatePicker.showDatePicker(
        context,
        minDateTime: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - firstYearDiff),
        maxDateTime: DateTime.now(),
        dateFormat: format,
        onChange: (dateTime, selectedIndex) {
          controller.value = dateTime;
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

вот сам код реализации пикера из библиотеки

```
void _showDatePicker() {
  DatePicker.showDatePicker(
    context,
    onMonthChangeStartWithFirstDate: true,
    pickerTheme: DateTimePickerTheme(
      showTitle: _showTitle,
      confirm: Text('custom Done', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
    ),
    minDateTime: DateTime.parse(MIN_DATETIME),
    maxDateTime: DateTime.parse(MAX_DATETIME),
    initialDateTime: _dateTime,
    dateFormat: _format,
    locale: _locale,
    onClose: () => print("----- onClose -----"),
    onCancel: () => print('onCancel'),
    onChange: (dateTime, List<int> index) {
      setState(() {
        _dateTime = dateTime;
      });
    },
    onConfirm: (dateTime, List<int> index) {
      setState(() {
        _dateTime = dateTime;
      });
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь использовать async и await в слушателе onChange, допустим:

```
onChange () async {
final param = await ...;
setState(() {
_dateTime = param });
}
```